# Is there a way to detect specific cells are overlapping each other in mxGraph?

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

I'm inserting images on the editor by drag and drop. I want to detect if images are overlapping and if they are then make their border red.

Currently I'm modifying this "mxGraph.prototype.cellsMoved" to detect overlapping when the image is moved. I'm looking for a in-built mxgraph function which can detect if images are overlapping or not.

As you can see in the attached image that two images are overlapped and their border is set to red.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please can u post your cells moved code? I am trying to do something similar. thanks

Answer (score 0):

While mxCellsMoved is probably the correct place to put intersection checks, you can get the bounding box of a cell from `mxGraphView.getBounds` and call `mxUtils.intersects` on it and the target node.  Here's an example (untested):

```js
var graph = //mxGraph,
    view = graph.view,
    moved = //cells that have been moved
    model = graph.model,
    others = model.filterCells(model.cells, function(cell) {
       return moved.indexOf(cell) === -1;
    });
for(var m of moved) {
    for(var unmoved of moved) {
       if(mxUtils.intersects(view.getBounds(m), view.getBounds(unmoved)) {
          //handle intersection logic
       }
    }
   
}
```

This could be optimized, but the general idea should work.